# Oracle error "No more data to read from socket" When Using jdbc:oracle:thin

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have an Oracle error **No more data to read from socket**. 
It's a connection using **ColdFusion** datasource jdbc:oracle:thin

how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this is the result of a really serious Oracle error, like an ORA-600 or ORA-7445.  Ask your DBA to look for any trace files.

Answer (score 1):

use this - 
conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

not this-
conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Comment: Can you add any context on the difference between TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE ?